# Framework Python Open-ID

Tags: python, google-openid

Galera, estou com um problema.

Não acho que o stack seja o melhor lugar para perguntar mas não sei exatamente aonde perguntar isso.

Como todos sabem, o OpenId 2.0 não terá mais suporte da google o que nos obriga a alterar nossas aplicações para OpenId Connect(Oauth2.0).

Depois de algumas pesquisas, encontrei dois frameworks de Oauth2.0:

https://github.com/google/oauth2client

https://github.com/rohe/pyoidc

O problema é que nenhum dos dois frameworks possuem uma documentação clara sobre como serem utilizados e, antes de me aprofundar sobre algum deles para buscar a solução, resolvi perguntar aqui se alguém já utilizou algum deles ou se conhece algum outro.

Acredito que esta pergunta possa ajudar muitos aqui na comunidade, mas vou entender se optarem por fechar essa pergunta.

Obrigado

Comment: Você pretende usar OAuth só para autenticar (sua app é só um cliente) ou para emitir tokens (sua app é usada por outras apps para autenticação) ?

Comment: Só para autenticar

Answer (score 1):

Caso voce queira acessar so os servicos do Google existe um lib chamada gdata[1] mantida pelo Google, aqui tem a documentacao[2], aqui[3] o Google fala um pouco mais sobre ela.

Caso queira uma lib para conectar com Oauth2.0 da uma olhada aqui[4]

- [1] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gdata
- [2] http://pythonhosted.org//gdata/
- [3] https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib
- [4] https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2